# Word meaning something which is in a predefined location

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider a situation where there are a few typical places in which an object will usually be located. In rare cases, the object may be located elsewhere. I am looking for a word to describe the situation in which the object is in one of its typical locations. Something like "typically-positioned", but a single word.

**EDIT:** For example, consider the winner's podium in the olympics. There are 3 defined locations. If someone were to stand on one of these she would be in one of the "standard" locations. If someone were to stand with one foot in one part and another foot in the other, she would not be in one of the "standard" locations.

How would you describe a person that is in one of the "standard" locations?

**2nd EDIT:** Another example that does not involve a person: Consider a molecule is positioned most of the time in one of 3 locations. Occasionally the molecule is not in one of these locations.

How would you describe the molecule when it is in one of its typical positions?

Comment: "Put away"? When I'm at home and my husband wants to know where the scissors are, I tell him that I "put them away"... and he knows to find them in the office, with the other supplies or in the kitchen with the knives.

Comment: @Catija thanks - in my case these are not objects that can be "put" and these typical locations are not really "away". Also I am looking for a single word.

Comment: Many "single word requests" can't be filled by a single word. I'm not saying this can't, I'm just saying that you should be prepared for it not being possible. Don't get hung up on "single words"... they're not **always** better than multiple words.

Comment: @Catija I know - but one can always hope :)

Comment: @Bitwise: Not that the away in 'put away' doesn't have to be literally far away. It's a phrasal verb.

Comment: @Catija see my edit as to why something like "put away" does not fit.

Comment: @Bitwise: It's common courtesy to include the word 'EDIT' after a major edit. Especially when you totally change the question. From 'something' and 'an object', you went to 'someone' and 'a person'. Not cool.

Comment: @TusharRaj I apologize about the marking - but it is just an example - my specific case does concern an object, not a person. So the question is exactly the same as it was originally. If you think this is an issue I can change the example to being something else that cannot be "put" - for example a planet that can be in a typical location.

Comment: @Bitwise: Yeah, I think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Yiu might refer to them as being ***out of position*** I don’t think there’s a single word for it.

Comment: @Catija I liked your answer. But in our house I usually say *It is in its proper place*. In my world everything would have a *proper place*.

Comment: @Bitwise As this is about technical usage, the best answer will be by asking someone (or looking at the literature) in your specific technical area.  In mathematics (specifically computational geometry), the term is 'standard position', but that may not be what other specific areas use.

Comment: Just a note-  when I suggested ***out of position*** I was answering the part where OP was talking about a person with one leg on one podium and the other on another.  The opposite of *out of position* is ***in position*** and could be used to say, for example, “the molecule is in position*** which might need to be qualified with 1,2,3  or A, B, C if there is more than one typical position.

Comment: If the particular position doesn’t matter you might say, “the molecule is in one of the three possible positions that allows the reaction to occur”

Comment: You could try "normal position", explaining on first usage what you mean by this phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

"The molecule is in its ***usual*** position."... or to use your own word from the question details, "The molecule is in its ***standard*** position."

Both "usual" and "standard" are unambiguous and understandable as the place that the object can be found most of the time.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I had in mind before posting the question, but I wanted to hear other opinions, or a single word that has this meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Try **fixed**, **planted**, **defaulted** (may be context sensitive), **asserted**, **secured**, **redeposited**, or **situated**.